# I keep getting error C2248: cannot access private member declared in class

Tags: c++

I have an assignment to create a programme using two objects to handle basic operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication and division) of rational fractions
for each of my functions it keeps giving me this error -error C2248:  'rational::add': cannot access private member declared in class 'rational'
except for each function.
I can't understand why as its the rational.cpp file calling a member of rational.h

```
// Assingment3.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include "application.h"
#include "rational.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "main function started!\n";
    application *myapp = new application();
    std::cout << "Application started!\n";
    myapp->run();
    delete myapp;
    std::cout << "Application terminated!\n";
    return 0;
}



//application.h

class application {

public:
    void run();
    application(); 
    ~application(); 



};


//application.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "application.h"
#include "rational.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

application::application() {}

void application::run() {

    int num1, den1, num2, den2;
    char sign;
    cout << "enter a rational number (numerator them denominator seperated by a space) \n";
    cin >> num1 >> den1;
    cout << "enter an operator(+,-,* or /)";
    cin >> sign;
    cout << "enter a second rational number (numerator them denominator seperated by a space) \n";
    cin >> num2 >> den2;
    rational *myrat = new rational();
    myrat->operation(sign,num1,den1,num2,den2);

    //std::cout << "Rational started!\n";




}
application::~application(){}


//rational.h
class rational {

public:
    rational();
    ~rational();
    void operation(char sign, int num1, int den1, int num2, int den2);
private:

     void add(int num1,int den1,int num2, int den2);
     void subtract(int num1, int den1, int num2, int den2);
     void multiply(int num1, int den1, int num2, int den2);
     void divide(int num1, int den1, int num2, int den2);


};

//rational.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "application.h"
#include "rational.h"
#include <string>

rational::rational(){
}

void operation(char sign, int num1, int den1, int num2, int den2) {
    rational dlg;
    std::cout << "operator started";
    if (sign == '+') {
    rational::add(num1, den1, num2, den2);
}
    if (sign == '-') {
        rational::dsubtract(num1, den1, num2, den2);
    }
    if (sign == '*') {
         rational::multiply(num1, den1, num2, den2);
    }
    if (sign == '/') {
         rational::divide(num1, den1, num2, den2);
    }
    else
        std::cout << "sign error\n";
}

void rational::operation(char sign, int num1, int den1, int num2, int den2)
{
}

void rational::add(int num1, int den1, int num2, int den2) {
    std::cout << "addition called \n";
    int den = den1 * den2;
    int num = (num1 * den2) + (num2 * den1);
    den1 = den;
    num1 = num;
    std::cout << "Answer :" << num << "/" << den << "\n";
}
void rational::subtract(int num1, int den1, int num2, int den2) {
    int den = den1 * den2;
    int num = (num1 * den2) - (num2 * den1);
    den1 = den;
    num1 = num;
    std::cout << "Answer :" << num << "/" << den << "\n";
}

void rational::multiply(int num1, int den1, int num2, int den2) {
    int den = den1 * den2;
    int num = num1 * num2;
    den1 = den;
    num1 = num;
    std::cout << "Answer :" << num << "/" << den << "\n";
}

void rational::divide(int num1, int den1, int num2, int den2) {
    int den = den1 * num2;
    int num = num1 * den2;
    den1 = den;
    num1 = num;
    std::cout << "Answer :" << num << "/" << den << "\n";
}

rational::~rational(){}
```

Comment: `operation` is a free standing function, not a `rational::operation`.

Answer (score 0):

The functions `add`, `subtract`, `divide`, `multiply` are not static functions, so you can't use the format: `class_name::function_name` to call them. Replace the call to each one of them with `this->function_name(...)` or just `function_name(...)` (from the current object) to use them.

Alternatively, you can make them static by changing their declarations to: `static ... function_name(...)`, and then call them like you did.

---

### Why `static`?

`static` means that the method belong to the class, and no to a specific object instance of it. It seems like your `rational` class's operations functions (add, substruct, etc...) don't need any `rational` class specific object members to perform their action. Because there is a logical explanation for those functions to be belong to the class, and not to a specific instance of it (you can call the same method with different parameters, and get the desired result, independently of the current object state), you can declare those method as static methods.

[Read more about `static`](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/812-static-member-functions/)

---

### Edit:

One more mistake that I just noticed in, is that your definition of the function `operation` is: `void operation(char sign, int num1, int den1, int num2, int den2)`, which means that it is not belong to the class, and the definition of this function that does belong to the class is doing nothing:

```
void rational::operation(char sign, int num1, int den1, int num2, int den2) {
```

}

Remove the `void operation(char sign, int num1, int den1, int num2, int den2)` definition, and move the content into the class's function definition that mentioned above.

Comment: Changing their declarations to ```static``` doesn't help as I keep getting the exact same error. Doing the ```this->```brings up its own new errors - ```error C2355:  'this': can only be referenced inside non-static member functions or non-static data member initializers```

Comment: @Nyx you can't combine both ways. `this` belong to non-static method, and `static` keyword makes the function `static`. All you have to do, is to add `static` keyword before each of those 4 lines: `void add(....); void subtract(...); void multiply(...); void divide(....);`, and make them: `static void add(....); static void subtract(...); static void multiply(...); static void divide(....);`. This way you can leave the rest of your code as it is in your post.

Comment: I had tried each separately. but neither worked. Fortunately, all my problems seem to have stemmed from the problem with ```operation()``` that you noticed in the edit. Changing it to ```void rational::operation(char sign, int num1, int den1, int num2, int den2) ``` in rational.cpp fixed everything. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Nyx it is wrong to use the form `clasname::function` for non-static functions.